# Vue multiselect not getting id and name

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have used vue multiselect in my form and I have made the options dynamic as autocomplete by axios post . I am returning only id and name from the controller to js file but it is displaying all the properties of option

This is My form

```
<multiselect v-model="form.books" :options="options" :loading="isLoading" :internal-search="false" @search-change="getData" :multiple="true" :close-on-select="false" :hide-selected="true" :limit="5" :internal-search="false"></multiselect>
```

This is my vue js file

```
Vue.component('coupon-form', {
    mixins: [AppForm],
    data: function() {
        return {
            form: {
                name:  '' ,
                description:  '' ,
                valid_from:  '' ,
                valid_till:  '' ,
                discount:  '' ,
                enabled:  false,
                books:[],
            },
            isLoading: false,
            options: [],

        }
    },
    methods: {
        getData(query){
            this.isLoading = true;

            axios.post('/admin/books/find/'+query)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                this.options = response.data;
                this.isLoading = false;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.isLoading = false;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This is my controller

```
public function find($books)
    {
        $search = $books;
        $books = Book::select('id','name')
                        ->where('id','like',"%$search%")
                        ->orWhere('name','like',"%$search%")
                        ->orWhere('sku','like',"%$search%")
                        ->orWhere('sale_price','like',"%$search$")
                        ->limit(5)->get();
        return $books;

    }
}
```

As we can see I am selecting the id and name of the Book Model but I am getting many properties of Book like this

[image]

And I want to show the name in the options and in the v-model I want to have id 
How to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need new field in your data and watcher for `value` so try something like this:

```
<multiselect v-model="selected"...></multiselect>
data () {
    selected: []
    ...
},
watch: {
    selected (newValues) {
         this.form.books = newValues.map(obj => obj.id)
    }
}
```

I think that is what you need.

I found a lot of issues about that and package doesn't have prop for that.

You can read more on there: [link1](https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect/issues/263), [link2](https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect/issues/133)

Good luck!

Comment: But in my v-model I am getting object . I just want id in there ?? How to do that

Comment: Ok I am waiting

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('books')->select('id,name')->where('id','like',"%$search%")
                    ->orWhere('name','like',"%$search%")
                    ->orWhere('sku','like',"%$search%")
                    ->orWhere('sale_price','like',"%$search$")
                    ->limit(5)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
    <div> 
        <multiselect  v-model="yourForm.bindThis" :options="options" :custom-label="showItems" placeholder="Select one" :label="options.name_of_a_column_from_record" :track-by="options.id_of_record" :multiple="true"></multiselect>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect';

data(){
   return{
      options: [],
      yourForm: {
        bindThis: '',
      }
   }
},

methods:{
   showItems({data}){
      return `${data.name_of_a_column_from_record}`;
   }

}
</script>
```

Let me know if it did the magic

Answer (score 0):

Add track-by and label props.

```
               <multiselect
                  v-model="form.users"
                  :options="scholars"
                  :multiple="true"
                  :searchable="true"
                  label="name"
                  track-by="id"
                  >
              </multiselect>
```